# Cambiar la ubicación de la librería de paquetes de R

Tags: r

He instalado R, pero la ubicación por defecto de la librería de paquetes, es decir, la carpeta o fichero en la que son instalados y desde la cual R los recupera, no se encuentra accesible. Por ejemplo: no tengo permisos para escribir en esa carpeta.

Otro caso de uso es que deseo contar con un conjunto de paquetes en una librería y otro conjunto de paquetes en una librería diferente, para así aislar análisis independientes que estoy realizando o porque requiere versiones muy específicas de cada paquete.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar esta ubicación a otra diferente? ¿Tengo otras opciones?

Comment: ¡Hola! Si ejecutas `?install.packages` (función empleada para la instalación de paquetes), la variable `lib` permite elegir la carpeta en la que quieres instalar el paquete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada:

- Hay 3 niveles de configuración 1) El del sistema 2) El del usuario 3) el del proyecto o de la carpeta. Si trabajas en un entorno corporativo, seguramente no tengas acceso al nivel 1, pero si puedes trabajar con los otros
- Si la carpeta de las librerías fue configurada en el nivel del sistema y no tienes acceso a modificarlo, deberás pedir a la gente de IT que lo haga, sino, aún podrás agregar una nueva carpeta y establecerla por defecto a nivel de usuario o proyecto, pero ciertamente la carpeta configurada a nivel sistema seguirá existiendo para R.

Configuración:

En principio, podemos decir que la carpeta o carpetas para las librerías, inicialmente pueden establecerse configurando las variables `R_LIBS` o `R_LIBS_USER` o `R_LIBS_SITE`, tal como se explica en `help("Startup")`, estas variables pueden escribirse en archivos o también configurarse como variables de entorno. Dirk Eddelbuettel hizo un buen resumen de dónde y como configurar este dato ([ver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417179/6836377)):

- Modificar los archivos del sistema como `.Renviron` o `.Renviron.site` si tiene los permisos adecuados. (Su ubicación depende del SO)
- Si no, modificar el archivo de usuario `~/.Renviron`
- Alternativamente, se puede modificar las variables de entorno `R_LIBS` o `R_LIBS_USER` o `R_LIBS_SITE` a nivel del sistema si tienes los permisos adecuados
- Si no, se puede modificar las variables `R_LIBS` o `R_LIBS_USER` o `R_LIBS_SITE` a nivel de usuario.
- Por último, se puede invocar a `.libPaths(...nueva ruta válida...)` en sus archivos de inicio de `R` como por ejemplo en `.Rprofile`.

---

```
# Consultando variables de entorno
Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_USER')
Sys.getenv('R_LIBS')
Sys.getenv('R_LIBS_SITE')

# Mediante .libPaths() 
.libPaths()
```

Por otro lado, un esquema de trabajo orientado a un proyecto o carpeta individual permite establecer la carpeta de instalación de paquetes mediante el archivo `.Renviron` o incluso mejor mediante `.Rprofile` simplemente hay que editar o crear este archivo en la carpeta de trabajo o del proyecto, y R al iniciarse lo leerá y evaluará como cualquier código, podemos entonces agregar entonces:

```
.libPaths("nuevo_path_valido")
```

La carpeta tiene que existir, en cuyo caso se agrega y se la pone como primera en la lista de búsqueda, lo que la convertirá en la carpeta por defecto.

Este es el mecanismo que usa [`renv`](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/), y con esto respondo tu última pregunta. Esta librería que vendría a reemplazar a `packrat` permite mantener por proyecto un path "privado" para manejar las versiones específicas de los paquetes y sus dependencias,   el procedimiento básico, cuando se instaló `renv` es inicializar y activar el entorno, ir adicionando los paquetes que necesitemos y por último tomar una "foto" del entorno dóndes se registran todas las dependencias y las versiones, luego, si distribuyen el proyecto a otra persona, al abrirlo [`renv`](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/) se encargará de descargar e instalar las mismas versiones que requiere el proyecto.